Fullcalendar visibleRange not called when view is multiMonthYear
Fullcalendar's visibleRange is not getting called when initial view is multiMonthYear. I supose it doesn't reach the code since it doesn't even execute a console log inside the function.
I have tried using it as an object, as a function and adding it dynamically to the calendar after initialization, none of it works.


options = <CalendarOptions>{
    plugins: [multiMonthPlugin],
    initialView: 'multiMonthYear',
    multiMonthMaxColumns: 6,
    multiMonthMinWidth: 100,
    visibleRange: {
      start: '2024-05-22',
      end: '2024-07-25'
    },
  }



Only when i change the type of view it gets called, but I need it in a multiMonthYear view.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

visibleRange isn't applied to any of the month/year views as far as I know, because they operate on a fixed grid with the 1st of the month always on the top row.
